# Dynamic allocation with DOUBLE POINTERS

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, memory-management, new-operator

I have a base class Toy and derived classes Toy_remote_car amd Toy_battery_car.

I am doing this:

```
Toy** ptr;
ptr=new Toy*;
ptr[0]=new Toy_remote_car[1];
ptr[1]=new Toy_battery_car[1];/*this is completely wrong according to my teacher because i never created ptr[1]. Instead this is a misuse of memory according to him.*/
```

The above code(ptr=new Toy*) is creating a single pointer of type Toy(ptr[0]) which contains the object of derived class Toy_remote_car.

Now i want to write such a code:

->the number of Toy type pointers should not be predefined.

->instead i would call an add_toy function which would create a ptr that will point to the type of object i want. Furthermore if i call the add_toy function again, it should not assign the data to the previos ptr, but it should create a new ptr. The following convention may help:

```
ptr[0]=new Toy_remote_car[1];
/*we want to add more toys so add_toy function called. A check is applied.*/
/*The check checks that ptr[0] already contains a value so it creates another pointer ptr[1]*/
ptr[1]=new Toy_battery_car[1];
```

->furthermore i would be able to access all the previous data. In short:

```
ptr[0]//contains one type of data.
ptr[1]//contains another type.
//and so on
```

->so it would automatically create a pointer(ptr) of type Toy whenever a new Toy is being added.

I hope i have explained well what i am trying to implement in this code.

Please please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: **why in the world** are you allocating pointers on the free-store?!?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Toy **ptr = new Toy *[n];
```

where `n` holds the number of `Toy` pointers you want. Growing the array is hard, but it can be done:

```
// Add x to toypp, an array of n pointers
// very stupid, linear-time algorithm
Toy **add_toy(Toy *x, Toy **toypp, size_t n)
{
    Toy **new_toypp = new Toy*[n+1];

    // copy the old array's contents
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
         new_toypp[i] = toypp[i];
    toypp[n] = x;

    // clean up
    delete[] toypp;

    return new_toypp;
}
```

Note the if the allocation fails, the old `toypp` and all pointers in it are not cleaned up. Really, if you want an array that grows, use a `vector<Toy*>` instead:

```
vector<Toy*> toy_ptrs(n);
```

and add toys with `push_back`.

Don't forget to `delete` every single `Toy*`, and with the first method, to `delete[]` the `Toy**`.

Handling various kinds of data can be done with inheritance.

Comment: And moreover n is unknown by all means as the toy store doesn't have specific number of toys.

Comment: @Spoilt: read up on vectors, they should be covered in every C++ book. The short story is: they're arrays that do (part of) the memory management for you and can grow dynamically.

Comment: @Spoilt, ignore the advice to use `vector` until you've covered it in class. It's a good idea to understand the hard concepts before you start using the easy shortcuts.

Comment: Okay I am gonna read it. But please confirm one thing. initially n=1 when add_toy is called. Then as add_toy is callled again and again, n increases by 1 each time. But ptr[0], ptr[1] and so on remains intact. Now as the number of toys in the store increases, the array of ptr is increase. Am i going in the right direction or your explanation doing a different thing??

Comment: @Mark Ransom then wat shud i do in ur opinion??

Comment: @spoilt, @Mark Random: added a pointer algorithm with some comments.

Comment: @Mark Random @larsmans...can anyone of you write the code if i want to use vector. I have gone throgh the topic but since i am doing all this on my own so i would appreciate if you write the code for me to help. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @Spoilt, I wrote an answer then realized it was the same as this answer. I think you are starting to understand, except that initially n=0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this code with a very simple logic. And this is working completely fine. Please give a look and do give opinions.

```
void add_toy_var()
{   
    temp=NULL;
    temp=tptr;
    tptr=NULL;
    delete[] tptr;
    C1.count1++;
    tptr=new Toy*[C1.count1];
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<(C1.count1-1); i++)
        {
            tptr[i]=temp[i];
        }
    }


    int choice2;
    cout<<"Which Toy you want to add?"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Remote Toy Car"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Batt powered toy car"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Batt powered toy bike"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Remote control toy heli"<<endl;
    cin>>choice2;
    if(choice2==1)
    {                       
        tptr[C1.count1-1]=new Toy_car_rem[1];
        tptr[C1.count1-1]->set_data();
    }
    else if(choice2==2)
    {
        tptr[C1.count1-1]=new Toy_car_batt[1];
        tptr[C1.count1-1]->set_data();
    }
    else if(choice2==3)
    {
        tptr[C1.count1-1]=new Toy_bike_batt[1];
        tptr[C1.count1-1]->set_data();
    }
    temp=NULL;
    delete[] temp;

}
```