# Adress Error while allocating memory for an object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a constructor for my class Polynom, but I don't what I'm doing wrong . Please help !

Monome.hpp

```
class Monome{
  int n; //degré du monome
  float a; // coeff du monome
public:

// Constructeur par valeur (défaut)
Monome(int=1 , float=0);
```

Polynome.hpp

```
#include "Monome.hpp"
class Polynome{
  int deg;
  Monome ** Poly;
public:
  Polynome(int);
};
```

Constructor Definition :

```
Polynome::Polynome(int Deg){
*Poly= new Monome[Deg*10]; // I'm having bad access in this line !
cout << "ok";
this->deg=Deg;

    for(int i=0;i<deg;i++){
    Monome A(i,0);
    *(this->Poly[i]) = A;
}     
}
```

Comment: You don't allocate `Poly` in your `Polynome` class, so you're dereferencing `Poly` causing the bad access. You need to `new` to allocate to your pointer, besides why do you need a pointer to a pointer?  Is there a reason not to use a `vector`?

Comment: seems like an answer to me but yeah he's right you need to create Poly before using it

Comment: I'm using pointers instead of vector because I'm trying to practice pointers and understand more how it works. What do you mean by I have to define Poly??? Because I'm already doing that in the class when defining it inside the class no ? @EdChum

Comment: I didn't say define, I said allocate, think about it, your member is a pointer to a pointer, this is not created automatically. Your error is dereferencing it without allocation you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721728/dynamic-allocation-with-double-pointers to see how to allocate correctly

Comment: In fact I understood, thank you very much. What I have to do is to allocate first the memory to poly **, then I'll allocate to the other pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Polynome{
  int deg;
  Monome ** Poly; -------> this is a double pointer, which means,  it is a pointer which store pointers
public:
  Polynome(int);
};
```

> ```
> *Poly= new Monome[Deg*10]; // I'm having bad access in this line !
> ```

In above piece of code what you are trying basically is accessing pointer stored in poly without actually givinig memory to poly. Due to this it is crashing.

Correct order is:

```
1. Allocate memory to poly as poly = new Monome*[n]; // where n holds the number of Monome pointers you want.
2. for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
         poly[i] = new Monome;
```

Comment: try to understand this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721773/5694959

Answer (score 0):

Well you are having a bad access cause you are accessing a field which does refer to a garbage value.

Instead of calling

```
*Poly= new Monome[Deg*10]; // I'm having bad access in this line !
```

You should write

```
Poly = new Monome*[Deg*10];
```

Comment: Nope, It's wrong, because your assigning a *monome to **monome. It's not working